# Rename file while using SFTP to append date

Tags: linux, ssh, sftp, mainframe, zos

I'm sending a file from a z/OS system to a Linux ftp sever using sftp.

I want to append the date to the filename once the file resides on the linux box.
(Ex: filename.txt becomes filename122308.txt)

I have tried the 'rename' command using 'date +%m%d%y' - the file was renamed but the flags were not executed (The filename became filename'date +%m%d%y'.txt

The 'cp' and 'mv' commands do not work... any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The commands are being sent via JCL control card. I don't think this approach will work.

Comment: How are you submitting the commands in JCL?  Are you executing a shell command from the JCL via the BPX* commands?

Answer (score 1):

Since sftp isn't running a shell, there's nothing to execute the `date` command. You're probably going to have to evaluate the new name you want on the sender's side, and then execute the sftp rename.

Another option is to send the files into a queue area (like a folder with your date string), and have a script on the linux box move/rename the received files accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Can you do it via the command line?  The options exists to execute sftp as...

```
sftp [[user@]host[:file [file]]]
```

...so you might execute...

```
export WHEN=`date +%m%d%y`
sftp theUser@theHost:filename$WHEN.txt filename.txt <<-!
thePassword
!
```

Comment: The commands are being sent via JCL control card. I don't think this approach will work.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to the Linux server? In that case you could just rename the files there. You could for instance use inotify to monitor the directory, and then have a script that adds the date to files whenever a new file is created in that directory.

[Here's](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=663950) a simple example in Python (although there are inotify bindings for most languages). The event you'll want to listen for is IN_CREATE.

Answer (score 0):

```
#Establish a local variable to store the LOGINID to be used
export USERID=xxxxx                                                  
#Establish a local variable to store the Path/file location on Remote machine
export REMOTEPATH=/some/path/    
#Establish a local variable to store the NAME of the remote Server
export TARGET=192.168.0.xx
#Establish a local variable to store the new component of the file name (in
#this case, a modification of Date)
export WHEN=`date +%m%d%y`                                                  
#Demonstrate that the USERID variable is set properly by echoing it out to the
#StandardOut
echo "User "$USERID                                               
#Demonstrate that the TARGET variable is set properly by echoing it out to the
#StandardOut
echo "Target Server: "$TARGET                              
#Demonstrate that the REMOTEPATH / server variable is set properly by echoing
#it out to the StandardOut
echo "Target Path "$REMOTEPATH                                    
#Demonstrate that the WHEN / date name modication variable is set properly by
#echoing it out to the StandardOut
echo "Date component of file "$WHEN                                  
#Just echo out that we're about to do something useful
echo "Sending file to REMOTE"                                        
#Simulate the user typing out a command by using the "echo" command.  We use
#the $REMOTEPATH and $WHEN variables to modify "what the user types" but when
#we're done, echo passes information into SFTP just like the user were sitting
#there typing in the #commands.  In this case, it should send in 
#"put /local/path/file /some/path/fileName09092009.txt"
#That is provided as the command list to sftp because of the single "-" that 
#says "get my list of commands from standard-input"  The -vvv is for verbose 
#(lots of diagnostics) and then the $USERID@$TARGET uses the USERID and TARGET
#variables to connect as user-at-server for the exchange.
#A passwordless SSH authentication is already in place, so no password 
#is needed.
echo "put  /local/path/file $REMOTEPATH/fileName$WHEN.txt " | \
    sftp -b - -vvv $USERID@$TARGET
#Just echo out that we're about to do the next step and change file
#permissions.
echo "Changing file Permissions on REMOTE"                
echo "Done"
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your mainframe SFTP client but many SFTP clients support using the ! prefix to run local operating system commands.  So you can copy the file to the new name before sending, then send, then remove the copy.

E.g.:

```
!cp filename.txt filename122308.txt
put filename122308.txt
!rm filename122308.txt
exit
```

If space is a premium, use mv twice instead of cp & rm.